# Question about functionals in normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

I have this problem: Let X be a nontrivial normed space such that $\left\| f+g \right\|<\left\| f \right\|+\left\| g \right\|$  for all pairs of linearly independent functionals $f,g\in {{X}^{*}}$ . Prove that for each nonzero $x\in X$ there exists a unique $f\in {{X}^{*}}$ with $\left\| f \right\|=1\wedge f(x)=\left\| x \right\|$.

I know how to prove existence, but not sure about uniqueness.

Comment: Suppose there are two such functionals $f,g$ for some $x\in X$. Show that $f$ and $g$ would be linearly independent. Conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g$ be two such functionals. Now note that 
$$
2 \lVert x \rVert = \lvert (f+g)(x) \rvert \leq \lVert f+g \rVert \lVert x \rVert.
$$
So we have $\lVert f+g \rVert \geq 2 = \lVert f \rVert + \lVert g \rVert$, which means $f,g$ are linearly dependent. So we can write $f = \alpha g$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $f(x) = g(x)$, we can conclude $\alpha = 1$.